What are examples of stones that can be used in cooking?
[This question might be better suited for geology.stackexchange].
The use of rocks (outside of salt) in cooking (making direct contact with the food) is documented in Mongolian cuisine and Native American cuisine.
I wanted to get a list of all the possible rocks/stones I could safely add to a dish while cooking.
As an added bonus:
It's become recently well known that using a cast-iron pan or adding a block of iron while cooking soups and stews can raise trace iron levels in food.
I am curious if for the suggested stones/rocks a list of trace elements can be mentioned. That would be interesting to know (ex: is there a rock that releases trace amounts of zinc while cooking with and is safe to use in food).
I guess a starting answer would be trying to classify what kinds of rocks/stones would ancient Native Americans or Mongolians encounter in their environment and likely use for cooking. Native Americans in particular were known to use clay balls fashioned for the purpose of being heated up and used to boil stews.

I suspect that the answer will be "whatever was on hand". Highly unlikely that they found that certain rocks gave trace elements and subsequent improvement in health in some way. Would also depend on the style of cooking - earth ovens will just use whatever, but dropping rocks into dishes to heat - you'd want clean, hard smooth stones so as to not waste food by it getting caught in a rough surface on the rock and hard so that they don't drop grit on heating (i.e. no sandstones or mudstones).

I can see components fitting more into the History SE rather than Geology, though the trace elements certainly fit in Geology; but are easily searched once you know rock types.

I’m voting to close this question because it asks for a list of answers. As most Stack Exchange sites, we don't accept big-list type questions.

FWIW, the forms in which dietary minerals are present in rock tend not to be the forms in which humans can metabolize them. You could boil a bunch of iron ore in your soup and the soup would contain a lot of iron, but that iron would mostly pass through your body without being absorbed.

In contrast, plants are great at absorbing these minerals (they do live on dirt, after all), and even at converting them into bioavailable forms. Eat plenty of those!

@rumtscho is there an option to open this as a community-wiki?

@SidharthGhoshal that use of community wiki has been discouraged for over a decade. Really, it is a fun question, and I hope you can find out the correct answer - I'm afraid we're just not equipped to arrive at that answer

For the community wiki policy, see https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/. It clears up that it's explicitely not meant to be used on questions which are otherwise closable, and there is a strong recommendation against using it for questions at all. This has been established in 2011, and has worked well ever since.
